# How is epoll optimized by shared memory?

Tags: c, linux

I have seen that one of the optimizations in `epoll` than `select` or `poll` is that **epoll uses shared memory to communicate between user space and kernel space**. How does epoll do it?

```
struct epoll_event events[MAX_EVENT_NUMBER];
...
while(1)
{
        int epcnt = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EVENT_NUMBER, -1);
        for(int i=0; i<epcnt; i++)
        {
            ....
        }
}
...
```

In my opinion, Assume that epoll doesn't use shared memory. `epoll_wait` need to copy data -- the `events` array, between user space and kernel space **twice** in each circulation.

However, if `epoll` uses shared memory, the kernel need to create an shared block for communication. Then in each circulation, firstly, `epoll_wait` still need to copy data from shared block to user place. After the data of shared block was modified, it is still necessary to copy it to the user space, such of the first element address of event.

So, it seems that no matter `epoll` uses shared memory or not, the times of copying data is same. How do `epoll` optimize the copy operation between user space and kernel space by shared memory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "shared memory." In both poll and epoll the kernel copies its results in to a user-provided buffer.

The reason that epoll is faster than, say, poll, is because epoll has  a file-descriptor, and that file-descriptor can be used to store state (the list of fds) between calls.

With poll, every time you do a wait, the kernel has to re-register all fd's that you're waiting on and then unregister them before returning the results to userspace. So for n events happening over m file descriptors it takes O(mn) time. But with epoll it would take O(m + n) time.